# How to change the material2 md input placeholder font size and colour?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

How to change the material2 md input placeholder font size and colour?

[check this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ03O.png)

Answer (score 18):

**NOTE: /deep/ is now DEPRECATED, use *:host ::ng-deep* in place. Bear in mind ::ng-deep is technically also be deprecated and will be replaced by a combinator, but should be used for the time being**

The issue you are running into is with ViewEncapsulation. It's an annoyance, but from what I've been able to gather it is working as intended.

You do have the ability though with a few extra characters to change the style to your liking. You have to use the [special selector: /deep/](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors)

For instance if you wanted to change the colour of the placeholder text as described in your question you would create a style like this:

```
/deep/ .mat-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

This however won't change the underline style. If you wanted to change that you would just add another style like:

```
/deep/ .mat-input-ripple.mat-focused {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

If you still want to style the material component within a specific component you can use the [:host selector](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host):

```
:host /deep/ .mat-input-placeholder {
   font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: thats ok for changing `color`, but `font-size` will break everything. http://plnkr.co/edit/gFeD2OZdU0vYdAK6w7Pr?p=preview . Or: you have to apply `font-size` changes at multiple places

Comment: I've gotten around the font-size issue using the `:host` selector along with /deep/. This specifies it enough that it doesn't break the whole page. I've added an example

Comment: /deep/ has been deprecated as of 4.1 or 4.2. Now use ::ng-deep.

Comment: Thanks, I've kept the original answer but left a note

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own style in your styling css/scss for example:

```
md-input-container{  width: 100%;  .md-input-placeholder {
color: #a8a8a8;
padding: 0 12px;

&.md-float {
  &.md-focused,
  &:not(.md-empty) {
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.95);
  }
}  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me

In .CSS file

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-wrapper{
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :host selector in your css:

```
:host input.md-input-element {
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
 }
```